# Why express session sometimes does and sometimes doesn't make cookies?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using cookies like this on my express server :

```
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "someStringForSecretKey",
    resave: false,
    store: new redisstore({ client: RL }),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
    },
  })
);
```

and sending back the data via axios like this :

```
 axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
      axios.post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_HOSTNAME}/auth`, {
        username: userRef.current.value,
        password: passwordRef.current.value,
      }).then(function (response) .......
```

I am setting the session as such :

```
  req.session.user = req.body.username;
  req.session.save(()=>{
    if(req.session.user ){
      res.status(200).json({
       foo : true
      });
        }
```

Now to my surprise the cookie is sometimes set and sometimes isn't. There is no pattern.
Why express session sometimes does and sometimes doesn't make cookies?

Comment: Don't worry about it. The session still works right? Does the session stop working?

Answer (score 0):

```
httpOnly: true,
```

Creates undesirable behavior in which it sometimes creates the cookie and sometimes doesn't.

```
httpOnly: false,
```

Solved the issue.